# How to assign Json object to a C# varable

Tags: c#

I have a simple question regarding c#.

I have an API where I fetch a JSON object:

```
{
    "id": 455333,
    "rev": 32,
    "fields": {
        "System.AreaPath": "Organization\\Department\\Name",
     }
   ...
}
```

Getting the URL is not a problem but displaying the `fields` is what I don't know how to do.

If `fields` was an array I could do something like this:

```
class Results {
  public int id {get;set;}
  public int rev {get;set;}
  public List<Fields> fields {get;set;}
}

class Fields {
 ...
}
```

I used the above code in other array object and it works, but in this case `fields` is not array, and `"System.AreaPath"` contains a `.` dot.  This means inside my `Fields` class I can not declare a variable to hold the path address because `public string System.AreaPath`
will not work.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Fields isn't an array, but it's probably a dictionary.

Comment: @mason thanks, changing to Dictionary works. I never used that before. Anyway, if you have a Dictionary like this `{'foo.bar': '3'}` how do you echo `foo.bar` ?

Comment: 'foo.bar' is just a string. It's not a property name in C#. But let's say you had some JSON that represents an object, not a dictionary. Each of the JSON libraries in .NET have ways to deal with JSON properties names that aren't valid C# property names, such as applying an attribute to the property. You haven't told us what JSON deserialization library you're using.

Comment: @mason I am using `@using Newtonsoft.Json` and I deserialize it using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WorkItem>(responseBody);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this class

```
public class Results {
  public int id {get;set;}
  public int rev {get;set;}
  public Dictionary<string, string> fields {get;set;}

  //or instead you maybe need
   public Dictionary<string, object> fields {get;set;}
}
```

you can use this code to deserialize your json

```
Results results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Results>(json);

string areaPath = results.fields["System.AreaPath"];
```

Comment: Thanks, I am getting for some reason the following error: `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an express of type 'object'`

Comment: Thanks, I changed to Dictionary and it worked.